# Filter rows by using group by clause in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am trying to write a SQL query (for SQL Server) to search for all rows in a table that meets certain conditions that does not involves aggregation function but still need group by clause.

For example, let's say we have a table as shown below:

```
Student_Name | Borrow_Date | Book_ID
------------------------------------    
Jason, 25-01-2012, 1
Jason, 25-01-2012, 2
Jason, 25-01-2012, 3
Becky, 26-01-2012, 1
Becky, 26-01-2012, 4
Linda, 25-01-2012, 1
Linda, 25-01-2012, 3
```

I want to find out all the students from table above who borrowed books with book_id 1 and 2; or books with book_id 1 and 3, on the same day (borrow date).

So the result should be:

```
Jason, 25-01-2012, 1
Jason, 25-01-2012, 2
Jason, 25-01-2012, 3
Linda, 25-01-2012, 1
Linda, 25-01-2012, 3
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: so what makes you think you need a group by clause?

Comment: And what if a student borrowed books 1, 2 and 3 the same day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find all students who borrowed one of these combinations of books, I would recommend using aggregation:

```
select student_name, borrow_date
from t
group by student_name, borrow_date
having sum(case when book_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       (sum(case when book_id = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 or
        sum(case when book_id = 3 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
       )
```

To get the details from the table, you need to join it back in:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select student_name, borrow_date
      from t
      group by student_name, borrow_date
      having sum(case when book_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
             (sum(case when book_id = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 or
              sum(case when book_id = 3 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             )
     ) tsum
     on t.student_name = tsum.student_name and t.borrow_date = tsum.borrow_date
```

The one difference from your results is that this returns bookid =2 for "Jason", but that seems consistent with your description.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The first part makes perfect sense, but I think when you join it back with the original table, it would not work if there was an additional row -

"Jason, 25-01-2012, 4"

as the join is based on student name and borrow date

Comment: @AshishSachdeva . . . Your description is not fully clear on what to do when other books are borrowed.  If you want those three bookids only, then add a `where` clause to the outer query:  `where bookid in (1, 2, 3)`.